# Missing required parameter: redirect_uri in spotify clone

Tags: reactjs

why do I get this error "Missing required parameter: redirect_uri" while cloning the spotify app

```
export const authentication="https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
const redirectURI="http://localhost:3000/";
const clientID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const scopes= [
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-read-recently-played",
    "user-read-playback-state",
    "user-top-read",
    "user-modify-playback-state",
];

export const loginUrl=`${authentication}?client_id=${clientID}?redirecturi=${redirectURI}${scopes.join("%20")}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
```

Comment: Replace `?redirecturi` with `&redirect_uri` in the last line

Comment: thankyou for that. I mistakenly put a ? insted of &

Answer (score 1):

you wrote `?redirecturi=` insted of `?redirect_uri=`

Comment: If that's the only issue, the question should have been closed as a typo

Comment: @camille by looking at error i think thats only problem